# Update and set Joins Table and Derived table

Tags: sql-server

I want to update the AddressL1, AddressL2 and City of my SalesOrderNumber:

To:  AddressL1: 4 Pullum St. 
Address L2: Birkenhead
City: Auckland

My code is:

```
SELECT
    TOP (200) dbo.SalesOrder.SalesOrderID, dbo.SalesOrder.SalesOrderNo,
    dbo.SalesOrder.CustomerID, dbo.qryAddress.AddressL1,
    dbo.qryAddress.AddressL2, dbo.qryAddress.City
FROM
    dbo.SalesOrder
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.qryAddress ON dbo.SalesOrder.AddressID = dbo.qryAddress.AddressID
WHERE
    (dbo.SalesOrder.SalesOrderNo = 'so18050653')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following query

```
 UPDATE A 
    SET A.AdddressL1 = '4 Pullum St',
       A.Addressl2 = 'Birkenhead',
       A.City='Auckland' 
    FROM dbo.qryAddress A
    INNER JOIN dbo.SalesOrder S ON A.AddressID = S.AddressID
WHERE S.SalesOrderNo = 'so18050653'
```

Answer (score 0):

To update data in a database you use the UPDATE command. Good reference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) and for subqueries look [here](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/update-statement/update-using-subqueries.php). For your case you need a sub select command on the WHERE clause to get you the AddressID from the SalesOrderNo key that you have. Be warned that this will updated any address that is tied to the SalesOrderNo. It might be a good idea to run the subselect first on its own to see what it returns. It should return a single AddressID.

```
UPDATE qryAddress a
SET AdddressL1 = '4 Pullum St',
   Addressl2 = 'Birkenhead',
   City='Auckland'
WHERE a.AddressID IN (SELECT s.addressID FROM SalesOrder s WHERE SalesOrderNo='so18050653')
```

Comment: Thanks but im getting an error that says "Update or insert of view or function QryAddress failed because it contains derived field.

Comment: The view is created from some source tables. See if you can find what the source tables are for the view and update those directly.